# I created a list using hash, but the information is always deleted after finishing the program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I started studying Ruby recently and I was looking for a challenge so I decided to create this program.

I created a program using hash, to create a list of products, where it stores the name and value.

However, I would like the products registered within the hash to remain there even after finishing the program.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how I could do it?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMlzd.png)

Comment: You could write the hash to a separate file (JSON for example) or save it to a database.

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The hash and every other variable will always be cleared from memory when your program ends. While your program is running, it stores everything in the RAM, and then clear all the memory it's using after finishing.

In order to recover the value from your Hash after exiting your program, you need to persist this information somehow. Using a database or storing it in a file. As someone suggested, you could store it in a JSON file, for example. You could do it like this:

1. Create an empty file in the same directory of your Ruby script named products.json
2. Use the Ruby `json` library to load the file content as a hash at the start of your program
3. Update the file before exiting the program

A working example:

```rb
require 'json'

begin
  products = JSON.parse(File.read('products.json'))
rescue StandardError
  puts 'Ainda não existem produtos cadastrados. Criando nova lista'
  products = {}
end

loop do
  puts 'Escolha uma opção'
  puts '1 - Adicionar o item e o valor'
  puts '2 - Sair'
  print 'Opção: '

  option = gets.chomp.to_i

  if option == 1
    print 'Digite o nome do item: '
    key = gets.chomp
    print 'Digite o valor do item: '
    value = gets.chomp

    puts "O produto #{key} com o valor de R$#{value} foi cadastrado com sucesso!"
    products[key] = value
  elsif option == 2
    File.open('products.json', 'w').write(JSON.pretty_generate(products))
    puts 'Fim'
    break
  else
    puts 'Opção inválida'
  end
end
```